# Orchard CMS Widget to list Documents uploaded

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

The Orchard.Media module allows you to upload and manage images, documents, etc.

Does it support a Widget to list Documents so that a user can download any?

If not, does the Orchard.Media module provide API to write such a widget in a separate module?

Thakns

Answer (score 0):

Create a projection query, filter on the Document content type. You can then use that query in a projection widget.